How to properly clean up non-serializable states associated with a Ray object?
Suppose I have a Ray actor that can create a Ray object that associates with some non-serializable states. In the following example, the non-serializable state is a temporary directory.
class MyObject:
    pass

_non_serializable_states = {}

@ray.remote
class MyCreatorActor:
    def create(self):
        ref = ray.put(MyObject())
        _non_serializable_states[ref] = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        return ref

I want the following on_evicted function to be triggered on the creator actor's worker process when ref is evicted, i.e., when the Ray distributed reference counting for the Ray object is zero.
def on_evicted(ref):
    shutil.rmtree(_non_serializable_states[ref])
    del _non_serializable_states[ref]

How can I modify MyCreatorActor.create to register on_evicted?
Is there a Ray API similar to weakref.ref(obj, callback) to register such a callback?
